# Speech-to-text openai with Next js returns incorrect text in Safari

Tags: next.js, speech-to-text, openai-whisper

I have a project, and here's a small copy of it, specifically the logic for record voice (https://github.com/ZaharBerku/openai-speech-to-text). When I turn it on in Chrome, everything is fine, it transmits the text word for word, but when I do the same thing in Safari, it returns something completely different, what could it be? I will also provide my code here, but you can also see it on Github.

**useRecordVoice.js**

```
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { blobToBase64 } from "@/utils/blobToBase64";
import { createMediaStream } from "@/utils/createMediaStream";

export const useRecordVoice = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  const [mediaRecorder, setMediaRecorder] = useState(null);
  const [recording, setRecording] = useState(false);
  const isRecording = useRef(false);
  const chunks = useRef([]);

  const startRecording = () => {
    if (mediaRecorder) {
      isRecording.current = true;
      mediaRecorder.start();
      setRecording(true);
    }
  };

  const stopRecording = () => {
    if (mediaRecorder) {
      isRecording.current = false;
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      setRecording(false);
    }
  };

  const getText = async (base64data) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/speechToText", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          audio: base64data,
        }),
      }).then((res) => res.json());
      const { text } = response;
      setText(text);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const initialMediaRecorder = (stream) => {
    const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    mediaRecorder.onstart = () => {
      createMediaStream(stream);
      chunks.current = [];
    };

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (ev) => {
      chunks.current.push(ev.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
      const audioBlob = new Blob(chunks.current, { type: "audio/wav" });
      blobToBase64(audioBlob, getText);
    };

    setMediaRecorder(mediaRecorder);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      navigator.mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(initialMediaRecorder);
    }
  }, []);

  return { recording, startRecording, stopRecording, text };
};
```

**API speech-to-text**

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import fs from "fs";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import OpenAI from "openai";
import { env } from "../../config/env";

dotenv.config();

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

export async function POST(req) {
  const body = await req.json();
  const base64Audio = body.audio;
  const audio = Buffer.from(base64Audio, "base64");
  const filePath = "tmp/input.wav";

  try {
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, audio);
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
    const data = await openai.audio.transcriptions.create({
      file: readStream,
      model: "whisper-1",
    });
    // Remove the file after use
    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);

    return NextResponse.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error processing audio:", error);
    return NextResponse.error();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please give an example of the output from Chrome and Safari, and what was spoken, so we can compare.

Comment: @KathyReid I have added a link to a project that can be used as an example in both Safari and Chrome. As for what I say, it's not very important, for example, "Hello World"